# how to make javafx table cell selectable so that its contents can be copied

Tags: javafx, tableview, textselection

I am playing with the examples from PRO-JavaFX 8, an excellent book by the way.
I have a table cell with some text, and I would like to make the text selectable so that I can copy it.

Comment: Please can you post the code that you've tried?

Comment: a hint as broad as your question: you need a cellFactory that uses a not-editable TextField for showing the content :-)